# Programmatically access Sidekiq Config/What config options are there and where do they get set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In a Rails app, Sidekiq 7, has `config/sidekiq.yml` as well as the ability to create an initializer to set configuration.

I'm trying to figure out a) what configuration options are available, b) where they can be set, and c) how to check that sidekiq did get configured

I don't need (c) to be part of production code or logic, more like something I can use occasionally in Rails console to validate that configuration changes I have made have been accepted, so (c) could be satisfied by some sort of "dump the config at startup" feature (that I can't find if it exists).

What I have tried is:

```
> bin/rails c
irb> require "sidekiq/cli"
irb> Sidekiq::CLI.instance.parse
irb> Sidekiq::CLI.instance.config
```

This shows that `config/sidekiq.yml` appears to be used.  Cool.  Issue, though, is when I try to replicate the config in my initializer

```yaml
#:concurrency: <%= ENV.fetch("SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY") { 15 } %>
:timeout: <%= ENV.fetch("SIDEKIQ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS") { 25 } %>
:queues:
  - default
```

(note, `concurrency` is commented out here to hopefully "force" it to use the initializer:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.concurrency = 88
  config.redis = {
    url: ENV.fetch("SIDEKIQ_REDIS_URL")
  }
end

# configure_client omitted
```

This initializer does not generate an error but the value is not used when I do the `CLI.instance` stuff above.  So either the initializer does not allow this to be configured (and, if so, what *can* be configured there?) or my way of dumping the config isn't accurate (and, if so, how *do* I do that?).

I can't seem to find good docs on this and it seems that the internals of the config changed in version 7.

### Edit based on @Mike Perham's comment that `sidekiq -v` works:

Here is the output of `sidekiq -v`:

```
# bundle exec sidekiq -v


               m,
               `$b
          .ss,  $$:         .,d$
          `$$P,d$P'    .,md$P"'
           ,$$$$$b/md$$$P^'
         .d$$$$$$/$$$P'
         $$^' `"/$$$'       ____  _     _      _    _
         $:    ',$$:       / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
         `b     :$$        \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
                $$:         ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
                $$         |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
              .d$$                                       |_|
      

2023-03-08T14:25:30.331Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Booted Rails 7.0.4.2 application in development environment
2023-03-08T14:25:30.331Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Running in ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [aarch64-linux]
2023-03-08T14:25:30.331Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2023-03-08T14:25:30.331Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: https://sidekiq.org
2023-03-08T14:25:30.334Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Sidekiq 7.0.6 connecting to Redis with options {:size=>5, :pool_name=>"internal", :url=>"redis://redis:6379/1"}
2023-03-08T14:25:30.335Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Sidekiq 7.0.6 connecting to Redis with options {:size=>5, :pool_name=>"default", :url=>"redis://redis:6379/1"}
2023-03-08T14:25:30.336Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Firing startup event
2023-03-08T14:25:30.336Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Client Middleware: 
2023-03-08T14:25:30.336Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Server Middleware: Sidekiq::Metrics::Middleware
2023-03-08T14:25:30.336Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2023-03-08T14:25:30.338Z pid=434 tid=7l6 DEBUG: Firing heartbeat event
^C2023-03-08T14:25:38.874Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Got INT signal
2023-03-08T14:25:38.875Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Shutting down
2023-03-08T14:25:38.875Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Terminating quiet threads for default capsule
2023-03-08T14:25:38.876Z pid=434 tid=7ku INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2023-03-08T14:25:38.876Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Firing quiet event
2023-03-08T14:25:38.876Z pid=434 tid=7me DEBUG: Firing shutdown event
2023-03-08T14:25:38.979Z pid=434 tid=88i INFO: Pausing to allow jobs to finish...
2023-03-08T14:25:40.728Z pid=434 tid=7me INFO: Bye!
```

My `sidekiq.yml` is shown above, and I would expect it to show those values

Comment: See `Sidekiq::Config` in Sidekiq v7. `-v` will turn on verbose logging and output the global config hash on process startup.

Comment: @MikePerham You can see the output of `-v` above - it does not seem to print any config other than Redis config. Eg it doesn't show concurrency, queues, or timeout.  I can see that this is all modeled by the class you mentioned, but I'm not sure how to access the actual instance of it that's used by the server (this is for debugging and not some production hacky usecase)

Comment: My memory must be out of date. Perhaps that was lost in the v7 refactoring.

Comment: @MikePerham I guess I'm happy to sign up to restore it :)  I will open a GH issue https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5822 to discuss adding this back.

Answer (score 2):

I'm maintaining `sidekiq-cron` and we need, in some places, to access some of those Sidekiq settings.

Since Sidekiq v7, you can access all configuration options (even Redis settings too) via:

```
Sidekiq.default_configuration
```

You can check how to access them in other Sidekiq versions in this file: https://github.com/sidekiq-cron/sidekiq-cron/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/options.rb. We finally added this abstraction to clean up our code, as the Sidekiq API for that has changed over latest releases.

Comment: Based on my analysis this only returns the default values, not the actual values.  I have noticed that forcing the CLI to parse will populate the object returned by that method, but this makes me even more confused about exactly what is parsed when and where it is stored.